# Having issue with grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am unable to grep below string using grep .

Below is the output having string

```
omnidb -session 2017/03/31-918  -detail | sed -e 's/ //g' 

Objectname:bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com:/C'bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com[/C]'

Objecttype:WinFS

Objectstatus:Completed

Started:FriMar3122:00:132017

Finished:FriMar3123:06:582017

Objectsize:23519123KB

Backuptype:Full

Protection:Protectedfor90days
```

But when I am trying to grep using below command

```
omnidb -session 2017/03/31-918  -detail | sed -e 's/ //g' | grep bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com:/C'bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com[/C]'
```

I am getting null output. I have tried to use quotes as well without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following,

If you want to use single quote in `grep` you have to surround your searching string with double quote.

Use `\` for `/` , `[` and `]`

```
omnidb -session 2017/03/31-918  -detail | sed -e 's/ //g' | grep "Objectname:bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com:\/C'bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com\[\/C\]'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-F` with `grep`:

```
omnidb -session 2017/03/31-918  -detail | sed -e 's/ //g' | grep -F "bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com:/C'bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com[/C]'"
```

`-F` is for `--fixed-strings`. Then `grep` will ignore the characters like `[]` as regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes for `grep` pattern and need to escape the case square brackets as they are meant to specify ranges in regex like below

```
omnidb -session 2017/03/31-918  -detail | sed -e 's/ //g' | grep 
 "bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com:/C'bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com\[/C\]'"
```

But wait ! That is unnecessary use of `grep` where you could've finished with just `sed` like below :

```
omnidb -session 2017/03/31-918  -detail | 
sed -ne "s/ //g;/bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com:\/C'bbtsrvvie4.cone.bombardier.com\[\/C\]'/p"
```